# How to run Load Test without run duration

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Can we run the load test irrespective of time duration, for example, if i am running tests for 25 users then test will automatically stops, once all the users finished their scripts. please help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Use Test Iterations` property to `True` and `Test Iterations` to 25. 
The first property will overide the test duration property and second will force load test to execute 25 total tests. Since you have 25 virtual users in your test it will share them to your users and so each one will execute one test.

Check here for mor details:

- [Load Test Run Setting Properties - Test Iterations Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406976.aspx#loadtestrunsettingproperties_testiterations)
- [Test iteration setting in loadtest using vs 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910389/test-iteration-setting-in-loadtest-using-vs-2010/13915741#13915741)

Comment: I checked with above, it ran successfully but key indicator graph is showing constant user 25 till last second. I think users should decreases in the graph as tests gets completed. Please advice.

Comment: That does not mean that they are running tests. It's just the value you set. Check how may tests were exexuted instead and if you want to see the virtual users' activity check: [Analyzing Load Test Virtual User Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183349.aspx).