# How to load test for specific number of requests / users

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am using visual studio web performance testing, specifically the web service request testing feature. I have created my tests and what I would like to do is to test it a specific number of times or with a specific number of users.

For example, I want to call the service(s) 20 times each. Another scenario is if I have 30 constant users, I want those 30 to call each instance of my web service test once each, but in parallel (subject to core count etc). This means if there are 2 web service tests, then 30x2 = 60 calls in all, no more, no less.

Edited:
I tried using iterations and here is what I saw. Right now I have 1 web test which generates a new insurance quote When I use iteration count of 20 and set the "Use test iterations" to true, the quotes are generated 1 at a time. I can see this because I wrote an app to query the DB every 500 ms. When I run the same test keeping Use test iterations=false and with a constant load of 20 users, I can see the quotes generated in 'parallel' but I only want 20 to be generated.

In the above scenario, what I would like to happen is that after the 20th test has been generated, the load test should stop even if there is remaining runtime.

Thank you for your help/guidance
Sainath

Comment: What part of your question is not answered by the extensive Microsoft documentation on how to create load tests?

Comment: AdrianHHH - There is no way to limit the number of instances of tests run based on the users. That is what I am looking for an answer to. That is what I meant by 30*x2=60, no more, no less. Again I do not want to use iterations because that is synchronous.

Comment: Your requirement is very vague so far. If you edit the question to precisely describe the pattern of how you want the test to run then perhaps we can help you. You also say that you "*do not want to use iterations because that is synchronous*", can you explain this comment as I think you have not understood iterations?

Comment: Adrian - I tried using iterations. Right now I have 1 web test which generates a new insurance quote When I use iteration count of 20 and set the "Use test iterations" to true, the quotes are generated 1 at a time. I can see this because I wrote an app to query the DB every 500 ms. When I run the same test keeping Use test iterations=false and with a constant load of 20 users, I can see the quotes generated in 'parallel' but I only want 20 to be generated.

Comment: I think I figured out the solution. It was because of my "Test mix type" I changed it to "Based on the number of virtual users" Also I set the virtual user load to a constant 20 as wells as Iteration count to 20. When I ran the test, I could see 20 quotes instantly created and then portions of their data being updated(as expected). Also only 20 quotes were generated !!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the solution. It was because of my "Test mix type" I changed it to "Based on the number of virtual users" Also I set the virtual user load to a constant 20 as wells as Iteration count to 20. When I ran the test, I could see 20 quotes instantly created and then portions of their data being updated(as expected). Also only 20 quotes were generated.

The below link helped clarify a few of the terminology used
[Test iteration setting in loadtest using vs 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910389/test-iteration-setting-in-loadtest-using-vs-2010)